# Send ng-model content to controller in AngularJS after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the input form in html:

```
<span>
   Max:</br>
   <input ng-model="maxValue"></br>
</span>
```

If I want to show it on the page it works if it is done like this:

```
This is max:{{maxValue}}
```

The problem is that I don't have any idea about how to send it to the controller for later use.

In my particular case I load a page with a chart and after the page is loaded I want to be able to change the max value of y-axis of the chart by introducing the value with `ng-model`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _how to send it to the controller_ it should already be in **a** controller, how do you set the value?

Comment: ^ indeed. You can/should access it with `$scope.maxValue`. `ng-model` already binds it, so you can display it with `{{maxValue}}` in your HTML as long as it's within the same controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using components, you should specify that you want to update a model in controller.
So, to access it in your controller you should use something like:

`<input ng-model="$ctrl.maxValue"></br>`

Then, in your controller, you should be able to access `this.maxValue`

Comment: This is assuming they're using the `ControllerAs` syntax, which based on their question they're not.